# Ruby on Rails7: some actions results in show just for one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have four controllers.

Accounts, Databases, Folders and Contents

This links works perfectly.

```ruby
<li><%= link_to t('global.delete').capitalize, folders_destroy_path(folder_id: folder[:folder_id]), :onclick => 'return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')' %></li>
```

```ruby
<li><%= link_to t('global.delete').capitalize, databases_destroy_path(database_id: @database[:database_id]), :onclick => 'return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')' %></li>
```

Destroy folder

```
Started GET "/folders/destroy?folder_id=65f40c35329880e9e65206e7" for 83.32.215.26 at 2024-03-15 08:53:39 +0000
Processing by FoldersController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"folder_id"=>"65f40c35329880e9e65206e7"}
```

Destroy database

```
Started GET "/databases/destroy?database_id=65f40d38329880e9e65206e8" for 83.32.215.26 at 2024-03-15 08:57:31 +0000
Processing by DatabasesController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"database_id"=>"65f40d38329880e9e65206e8"}
```

With Accounts works too.

But NOT with contents.

This link...

```ruby
<li><%= link_to t('global.delete').capitalize, contents_destroy_path(content_id: content[:content_id]), :onclick => 'return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')' %></li>
```

behaves like this....

```
Started GET "/contents/destroy?content_id=65f2d3ac3298803b035533e3" for 83.32.215.26 at 2024-03-15 09:01:51 +0000
Processing by ContentsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"content_id"=>"65f2d3ac3298803b035533e3", "id"=>"destroy"}
```

In all cases, *HTTP method* and *uri path* + *uri query* are similar

But in Contents case, rails choose *destroy* as *id* parameter instead as an *action*.
For action choose *show*.
Same for other Contents actions as *enable* or *disable*

```ruby
ActionController::MissingExactTemplate (ContentsController#show is missing a template for request formats: text/html):
```

My */my_app/config/routes.rb* looks like this:

```ruby
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :contents
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  root 'welcome#index'

  get 'accounts/index'
  get 'accounts/show'
  post 'accounts/create'
  get 'accounts/edit'
  get 'accounts/destroy'

  get 'databases/index'
  get 'databases/show'
  post 'databases/create'
  post 'databases/update'
  get 'databases/destroy'
  get 'databases/backup'
  get 'databases/build'
  get 'databases/offload'
  get 'databases/restore'

  get 'folders/show'
  post 'folders/create'
  get 'folders/destroy'
  post 'folders/update'
  get  'folders/enable'
  get  'folders/disable'

  get 'contents/show'
  post 'contents/create'
  post 'contents/update'
  get 'contents/destroy'
  get 'contents/enable'
  get 'contents/disable'
  get 'contents/reprocess'
end
```

rails routes shows...

```bash
icalvete@dev:~/my_app$ bin/rails routes
                                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                                       Controller#Action
                        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                          devise/sessions#new
                            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                          devise/sessions#create
                    destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                         devise/sessions#destroy
                                contents GET    /contents(.:format)                                                                               contents#index
                                         POST   /contents(.:format)                                                                               contents#create
                             new_content GET    /contents/new(.:format)                                                                           contents#new
                            edit_content GET    /contents/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                      contents#edit
                                 content GET    /contents/:id(.:format)                                                                           contents#show
                                         PATCH  /contents/:id(.:format)                                                                           contents#update
                                         PUT    /contents/:id(.:format)                                                                           contents#update
                                         DELETE /contents/:id(.:format)                                                                           contents#destroy
                                    root GET    /                                                                                                 welcome#index
                          accounts_index GET    /accounts/index(.:format)                                                                         accounts#index
                           accounts_show GET    /accounts/show(.:format)                                                                          accounts#show
                         accounts_create POST   /accounts/create(.:format)                                                                        accounts#create
                           accounts_edit GET    /accounts/edit(.:format)                                                                          accounts#edit
                        accounts_destroy GET    /accounts/destroy(.:format)                                                                       accounts#destroy
                         databases_index GET    /databases/index(.:format)                                                                        databases#index
                          databases_show GET    /databases/show(.:format)                                                                         databases#show
                        databases_create POST   /databases/create(.:format)                                                                       databases#create
                        databases_update POST   /databases/update(.:format)                                                                       databases#update
                       databases_destroy GET    /databases/destroy(.:format)                                                                      databases#destroy
                        databases_backup GET    /databases/backup(.:format)                                                                       databases#backup
                         databases_build GET    /databases/build(.:format)                                                                        databases#build
                       databases_offload GET    /databases/offload(.:format)                                                                      databases#offload
                       databases_restore GET    /databases/restore(.:format)                                                                      databases#restore
                            folders_show GET    /folders/show(.:format)                                                                           folders#show
                          folders_create POST   /folders/create(.:format)                                                                         folders#create
                         folders_destroy GET    /folders/destroy(.:format)                                                                        folders#destroy
                          folders_update POST   /folders/update(.:format)                                                                         folders#update
                          folders_enable GET    /folders/enable(.:format)                                                                         folders#enable
                         folders_disable GET    /folders/disable(.:format)                                                                        folders#disable
                           contents_show GET    /contents/show(.:format)                                                                          contents#show
                         contents_create POST   /contents/create(.:format)                                                                        contents#create
                         contents_update POST   /contents/update(.:format)                                                                        contents#update
                        contents_destroy GET    /contents/destroy(.:format)                                                                       contents#destroy
                         contents_enable GET    /contents/enable(.:format)                                                                        contents#enable
                        contents_disable GET    /contents/disable(.:format)                                                                       contents#disable
                      contents_reprocess GET    /contents/reprocess(.:format)                                                                     contents#reprocess
                              jobs_index GET    /jobs/index(.:format)                                                                             jobs#index
                               jobs_show GET    /jobs/show(.:format)                                                                              jobs#show
                                         POST   /jobs/index(.:format)                                                                             jobs#index
                             jobs_create POST   /jobs/create(.:format)                                                                            jobs#create
                     modifications_index GET    /modifications/index(.:format)                                                                    modifications#index
                    modifications_create POST   /modifications/create(.:format)                                                                   modifications#create
        turbo_recede_historical_location GET    /recede_historical_location(.:format)                                                             turbo/native/navigation#recede
        turbo_resume_historical_location GET    /resume_historical_location(.:format)                                                             turbo/native/navigation#resume
       turbo_refresh_historical_location GET    /refresh_historical_location(.:format)                                                            turbo/native/navigation#refresh
           rails_postmark_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/postmark/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/postmark/inbound_emails#create
              rails_relay_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails(.:format)                                              action_mailbox/ingresses/relay/inbound_emails#create
           rails_sendgrid_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/sendgrid/inbound_emails#create
     rails_mandrill_inbound_health_check GET    /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#health_check
           rails_mandrill_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#create
            rails_mailgun_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mailgun/inbound_emails/mime(.:format)                                       action_mailbox/ingresses/mailgun/inbound_emails#create
          rails_conductor_inbound_emails GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                          rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#index
                                         POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                          rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#create
       new_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/new(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#new
           rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#show
new_rails_conductor_inbound_email_source GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources/new(.:format)                              rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources#new
   rails_conductor_inbound_email_sources POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources(.:format)                                  rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources#create
   rails_conductor_inbound_email_reroute POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/reroute(.:format)                               rails/conductor/action_mailbox/reroutes#create
rails_conductor_inbound_email_incinerate POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/incinerate(.:format)                            rails/conductor/action_mailbox/incinerates#create
                      rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs/redirect#show
                rails_service_blob_proxy GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/proxy/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                                  active_storage/blobs/proxy#show
                                         GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                                        active_storage/blobs/redirect#show
               rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/redirect/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations/redirect#show
         rails_blob_representation_proxy GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/proxy/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format)    active_storage/representations/proxy#show
                                         GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format)          active_storage/representations/redirect#show
                      rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                                       active_storage/disk#show
               update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                               active_storage/disk#update
                    rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)
```

Comment: You created the standard rails routes for contents using `resources :contents`. Then you created your custom routes, the routing engine is confused and thinks you want to show the content with extra parameters.  Either remove `resources :contents` or call the delete action with the proper method which is DELETE not GET.

Comment: It looks like you're encountering an issue where your `ContentsController` is not recognizing the destroy action correctly and is instead treating it as the id parameter for the show action. This is likely due to a conflict in your routes.

Comment: Don't use GET requests for destroy actions. See here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server

Comment: @dbugger , you are rigth. Can you anwser my question in order to vote you up?

Comment: @BenTrewern,  you have a point, but other controllers are working like this. I'm going to change my routes to be acurrate, but this is not the issue i 'm suffering. Thanks anyway

Comment: @engineersmnky - `edit` should be a GET -- it doesn't change anything. `update` should be a PUT or PATCH.

Answer (score 0):

Although many people tell me about the HTTP method, and they are rigth, this is is not my real issue because other controller work even with GET.

The real issue is *resources :contents* in my */my_app/config/routes.rb*

> You created the standard rails routes for contents using resources :contents. Then you created your custom routes, the routing engine is confused and thinks you want to show the content with extra parameters. Either remove resources :contents or call the delete action with the proper method which is DELETE not GET. –
> @dbugger

Deleting it, works perfectly.